# Cannot retrieve binder configuration in spring-cloud-stream 2.1.0

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream

As I see in the new version of spring-cloud-stream 2.1.0 (spring-cloud greenwich). In the class *org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory*

```
public class DefaultBinderFactory implements BinderFactory, DisposableBean, ApplicationContextAware {

private final Map<String, BinderConfiguration> binderConfigurations;

(...) 

@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
@Override
public synchronized <T> Binder<T, ?, ?> getBinder(String name, Class<? extends T> bindingTargetType) {

    String binderName = StringUtils.hasText(name) ? name : this.defaultBinder;

    Map<String, Binder> binders = this.context == null ? Collections.emptyMap() : this.context.getBeansOfType(Binder.class);
    Binder<T, ConsumerProperties, ProducerProperties> binder;
    if (StringUtils.hasText(binderName) && binders.containsKey(binderName)) {
        binder = (Binder<T, ConsumerProperties, ProducerProperties>) this.context.getBean(binderName);
    }
    else if (binders.size() == 1) {
        binder = binders.values().iterator().next();
    }
    else  if (binders.size() > 1) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Multiple binders are available, however neither default nor "
                + "per-destination binder name is provided. Available binders are " + binders.keySet());
    }
    else {
        /*
         * This is the fall back to the old bootstrap that relies on spring.binders.
         */
        binder = this.doGetBinder(binderName, bindingTargetType);
    }
    return binder;
}
```

It seems that the new approach is to load the binders from the application context instead of creating a new one. Besides there is a fallback to the old bootstrap, I guess that it is for using the binders that have not been changed the approach yet.

Seeing the code, a couple of questions come up:

- It seems that two binders, one with the new approach and one with the old one (with its own spring context) cannot coexist. Am I right?
- With the new approach (loading the binder from the application context), the binder cannot access to the binderConfigurations. This variable is used ONLY by the old approach. So is there another way to retrieve the configuration from the binder?

Also, I do not see it clear in the documentation:

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.1.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-stream.html#multiple-binders

On the one hand, in point 8.3.1 says:

> 8.3.1 Classpath Detection
>   By default, Spring Cloud Stream **relies on Spring Boot’s auto-configuration** to configure the binding process.

while in the point 8.4:

> 8.4 Multiple Binders on the Classpath (...) Each binder configuration contains a META-INF/spring.binders

Does it mean that is not posible to configure several binders without the old approach of using the spring.binders? Is there any configuration approach that I am not aware of?

Comment: That is correct. You still need the `spring.binders`. So nothing really changed. The change you're referring to was part of and in preparation for something that is not available at the moment.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky during startup, is there a way to **not** come to the fallback of loading the binders from a new application context but to find the binders in the current application context at first hand? 

we have some trouble, because, for instance, the newly created application context resets the LoggingContext, which was modified in the actual application context before.